# How to launch Android Studio from terminal on Windows (and Linux)?

Tags: linux, windows, android-studio

I'm struggling to understand how to open applications from shell.
When I use Atom, I can just run

```
$ atom .
```

command to open it in the current directory, but I don't know how to do it with Android Studio.

I don't know if it has something to do with aliases, environment variables or something else, but I'd like to know how this stuff works. I'd also appreciate a short comparison of the same problem on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On my winslow-7 machine there is an icon on the desktop named "Android studio".

I checked the properties of this icon, and in the *destination* field I've found:

**"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe"**

If I type that in a command prompt, Android studio opens normally.

A similar thing works in Linux too.

Basically, to run a program, you have to know where its executable resides; then you can ask the shell to run that executable. A few directories are searched automatically by the system and, if the executable resides in one of those directories, there is no need to indicate the full path - the name of the file suffices. The list of directories is an environment variable, PATH, for both windows and Linux.

This is a short and incomplete answer, though; your question asks a comparison and/or something more, but it is not clear and there would be a lot to say.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `studio64 .` command, your current folder will open in android studio.

This works if you've added the path of the `bin` directory of the android studio installation folder to environment variables. In my case, it is `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`.

This works the same as `atom .` or `code .`(VSCode)

The problem is, that it returns a bunch of warnings and stuff in the terminal before launching android studio. Also, if you close the terminal, the studio crashes.

It works but it's not purrfect.

Comment: does not seem to work on mac os (current ventura)

Answer (score -1):

For Windows:
Make a shortcut for your application and place in `C:\WINDOWS\System32`
you will be able to call it by the name of the shortcut.
For Linux:
`echo $PATH`